# Custom buttons in landscape and portrait in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation

i have created custom buttons in Xcode 5.In portrait view yellow button will have to display and in landscape mode blue button will have to display.my code is below:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

   UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

            if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {

                [self addYellowBtn1];


            }
            else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
            {

               [self addLightBlueBtn2];

            }

            return YES;
        }
```

when i run this app,at first portrait view displays the yellow button.but when i change into landscape both buttons were displayed.can anyone help me?

Comment: you need to remove or hide the buttons which are present in potraite mode.

Comment: your coding is fine , u need to modify something

Comment: how can i hide yellow button in landscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume that this is your `Portrait` method functionalities

```
-(void)addYellowBtn1:(id)sender

{
     // here hide the blue button
     [bluebuttonname setHidden:YES];

    // enable the yellow button

    [yellowbuttonname setHidden:NO];

 }
```

in `LandscapeRight`

```
-(void) addLightBlueBtn2:(id)sender

{
     // here hide the yellow button 

   [yellowbuttonname setHidden:YES];

    // enable the blue button

        [bluebuttonname setHidden:NO];

 }
```

Comment: initally hide your blue button in viewdidload, if u need any assistance i hope with u

Comment: have a happy day my friend,