# change custom label and button to landscape in xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation

i create a custom button and label in portrait mode and landscape mode separately as below:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {

        [self addButton1];
        [self addLabel1];

     }
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {

       [self addButton2];
       [self addLabel2];
}

    return YES;
}
```

if i run this code,in landscape mode both buttons and labels are displayed.
if i try this:

```
 else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
            {

               [self addButton2];
               [self addLabel2];
    [custombtn1 setHidden:YES];
    }
```

error:use of undeclared identifier.
can somebody help me?

Comment: see this s useful for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708422/custom-buttons-in-landscape-and-portrait-in-xcode-5/26708543#26708543

Comment: Xcode is an IDE that runs on OS X. I don't think it supports orientation changes or adding custom buttons to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the method:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

> This method is called regardless of whether your code performs one-step or two-step rotations.
>
> Parameters
>
> fromInterfaceOrientation
>   The old orientation of the user interface. For possible values, see UIInterfaceOrientation.

Additionally, you could hide unnecessary buttons.

```
addButton2.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {

        [self addButton1];
        [self addLabel1];
        addButton2.hidden=YES;
     }   if i use this,error appeared as:use of undeclared identifier

Comment: Replace orientation with fromInterfaceOrientation.